# jQuery Ajax PHP and CSV

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I don't have experience with CSV export in a particular scenario and would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction. Need to export array to CSV, but the problem is that Array's text may have multiple commas and during the export it splits the text by comma and adds to CSV in a separate column.

This is what I've got so far for Ajax (CSV generation code I found somewhere on the Internet):

```js
  $('#export-csv').on('click', function(){
    alert('export');
    var postId = 551;

    //call database and get data
    $.ajax({
        url:ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action': 'export_csv',
            'posts': postId,
        },
        success:function(data) {
          output.html(data);
          console.log(data);

          download_csv(data);


        },
        error: function(errorThrown){

        }
    });

    return false;



  });
  function download_csv(data) {
    var csv = 'Name,Title\n';
    data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });

    console.log(csv);
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'people.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

I get an Array  from PHP in the following format:

```js
["risk_communicate_consult", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…r ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,"]
["risk_monitoring_review", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…r ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,"]
```

After I export it to CSV, it splits array on every occurrence of ',' and adding those piece in CSV in separate columns.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your issue. It would be much clearer with some examples

Comment: @Phil I just updated the description, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because your column values may contain commas, you need to use a field identifier.

Typically, this is `"` wrapped around each column value. Any double-quote characters in your column values should be escaped by using two double-quotes

Try something like this...

```js
const data = [
  ["risk_communicate_consult", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…r ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,"],
  ["risk_monitoring_review", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…r ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,"] 
]

const csv = ['Name,Title'].concat(data.map(row => {
  return row.map(col => `"${col.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`).join(',')
})).join('\n')

console.info(csv)
```